# What is throw keyword without specifying thrown argument doing?

Tags: c++, exception

I need an explanation of what this code actually do, I can't really think of what I should specify to the search engine to find an answer to that, so I've decided to ask stackoverflow's community once again:

Let's say we have a function called `means`:

```
double means(double a, double b){
    double am, hm, gm;
    am = (a + b) / 2.0;   
    try
    {
        hm = hmean(a,b);
        gm = gmean(a,b);
    } 
    catch (bad_hmean & bg)
    {
        // do something
        throw;
    }
    return (am+hm+gm)/3.0;
}
```

And let's say function `hmean` inside `try` block does something that throws an exception which is a `bad_hmean` object. So the first `catch` block inside `means` function is triggered. It throws another exception, because of the line that contains `throw;`.

Now, our means functions was declared in for example, main function, in another try-catch block:

```
int main(){
    
    // variables, etc.
    
    try{
        means(a,b);
    }
    catch (bad_hmean & bg){
        // this catch block is being triggered
        // after means function throws the exception in it's catch block

        // block does something
    }
}
```

My question is - why is that, that in our function `means`, when it reads the line which contains just `throw` (in the catch block) without specifying the type of the exception, the catch in main is being triggered? How does the catch block in main know, which type of exception did `means` function throw? Is it that, that when we're declaring another throw in a catch block which already has been triggered by a certain type of variable - we don't need to specify the argument another time? How does it work?

Comment: It rethrows the current exception.  It's more useful in a catch-all block (`catch (...)`) where you don't have a reference to the caught object.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much, now I see.. Somebody correctly voted as a duplicate for this question.